# How to Jagged List C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a jagged array but due to the dynamic-ness of the data I am working with I do not want to waste resources creating a  a large jagged array.

I am currently doing:

```
int[][][] data = new data[Int16.MaxValue][][];
```

I do not how big the data set is, or is there a better way than doing it via Lists?

Comment: What will it be used for? It seems like a awfully large construction to me.

Comment: I second this opinion. @0xFF, please show us your problem at whole, so we can propose a more viable solution.

Comment: Your code snippet does not even compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use `List<T>`.

In this case, you would use `List<List<List<int>>>`.

Your array:

`int[][][] data = new data[Int16.MaxValue][Int16.MaxValue][Int16.MaxValue];`

will take up (2^16)^3 = 2^48 = way more storage space than you have,
not to mention that that declaration is not valid C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how much space you need when you initialize, then it would be best to use a dynamically resizing list.

Use a variable similar to this:

```
List<List<List<int>>> data = new List<List<List<int>>>();
```

This variable allows you to add `List<List<int>>`'s to it, and those lists contain `List<int>`'s, which of course contain `int`'s

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely do not want to use Lists, you can always replicate what Lists do under the hood: Create your array with a small number of elements, and when you reach the maximum, create a new array that is double the original's size, copy your existing array into it, and dispose of your original. Continue this pattern until you are done. I recommend using Lists instead, but this is how you would get around it if, for some reason, you just don't want to use Lists.

Answer (score -2):

In fact, you can create jagged arrays without defining second and further dimensions.

```
int[][][] jagged = new int[256][][];
```

But at large datasets it is more effective to use streaming data - i.e., combinations of `IEnumerable<T>`.